# How can I connect TestNG javadocs to Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, selenium-webdriver, testng

Although we can find TestNG javadocs, is there a way to download a srcs.jar and connect to Eclipse?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Steps:

1. Download the jar file based on your version of testng, [here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/t/Downloadtestng685sourcesjar.htm). The jar file name should be like `testng-version-sources.jar`
2. Extract to one of the locations.
3. Then go to the eclipse project that you want to add source jar.
4. Short cut: Double click on any of the testng class/annotation in your source code, like double click on `@Test` annotation.
5. Eclipse tries to open `Test.class` source code. As src jar is not yet present, gives option `Attach Source`. click on the button.
6. select `External location` radio button.
7. select the jar file, which is downloaded.
8. Click on `Ok`. you will get the source code for `Test.class` (of course, for all other testng classes as well)

Comment: Thanks for the responce Naveen. The TestNG version i have is testng-6.9.9.jar. But i cannot find the relevant testng-6.9.9-sources.jar.zip file on the site you provided or anywhere else i searched. Can it be because testng-6.9.9-sources.jar is still not available? Appreciate your support.

Comment: you can download from here https://www.versioneye.com/java/org.testng:testng/6.9.9. check for `testng-6.9.9-sources.jar`